# Cannot get custom component attribute from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-component

I have the following custom PrimeFaces Panel

In the page

```
<x:myPanel panelName="TEST123" />
```

And the class

```
    @FacesComponent(namespace="test",tagName="myPanel", createTag=true)
    public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    public MyPanel() {
           panelName = (String)getAttributes().get("panelName");
    }
}
```

Why when getting the attribute from the class itself does not work

```
getAttributes().get("panelName");  >> it returns null
```

I even tried to use the following as well, it also returns null at the class:

```
<f:attribute name="panelName" value="TEST123"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, behind the scenes, JSF creates the component and sets attributes as below:

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
myPanel.getAttributes().put("panelName", "TEST123");
```

It should speak for itself that it's not possible to set a component attribute before it's constructed. However, you're attempting to access it in the constructor!

You should access it in one of the standard `UIComponent` methods where you *actually* need it. E.g. `encodeBegin()` or so.

Comment: I understand now, it makes sense. Thanks a lot Balus appreciate the explanation also.
It worked :)
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Balus, as a continuation to what I am trying to do, what you suggested has worked, but I have found a different problem related to it, would you please check it:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412962/cif-and-rendered-is-not-working-at-all