# getAttributes().get("attributeName") in UIComponent constructor returns null

Tags: jsf, constructor, attributes, custom-component

I am testing JSF component but I am getting NullPointerException :( The problem code is :

```
@FacesComponent(value="mycomponent0")
public class MyComponent extends HtmlPanelGroup{

MyComponent(){
   String a0=this.getAttributes().get("attr0");
}

}
```

the taglib.xml's tag contains the attr0 attribute and the tags usage is :

```
<abc:mycomponent attr0="helloworld"></abc:mycomponent>
```

So my question is what causes the issue and how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Read BalusC answer here, for explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404268/cannot-get-custom-component-attribute-from-backing-bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I could figure out how to workaround the NPE issue...

I don't use constructor's body to get attributes but get attribute in overriden encodeBegin method;

```
@Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {      

        String id=this.getAttributes().get("id").toString();
        System.out.println("debug: attribute id="+id);

        String color=this.getAttributes().get("attr0").toString();
        System.out.println("debug: attribute attr0="+attr0);


        HtmlOutputLabel label0=new HtmlOutputLabel();
        label0.setValue("attribute attr0 value="+attr0);
        this.getChildren().add(label0);

        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }
```

So it's working and I think I am OK with this solution; I am not sure is it the most optimal way so please do share some snippets...